# I want to execute a function in another function before the second function executes in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project in react js. I want to execute a function in another function before the second function executes, here is the code:

```
const [expression, setExpression] = useState("");
const [result, setResult] = useState("");

const Logic = () => {
    if (expression.toString().charAt(0) === "0" && expression.toString().charAt(1) === "1" || 
    expression.toString().charAt(1) === "2" || expression.toString().charAt(1) === "3" || 
    expression.toString().charAt(1) === "4" || expression.toString().charAt(1) === "5" || 
    expression.toString().charAt(1) === "6" || expression.toString().charAt(1) === "7" || 
    expression.toString().charAt(1) === "8" || expression.toString().charAt(1) === "9" || 
    expression.toString().charAt(1) === "0") {
        setExpression(expression.replace(expression.charAt(0), ''));
    }
}
```

I want this function to run in another function before the code for the second function executes.

here is the code for the second function:

```
const Calculate = () => {
    Logic();

    setResult(expression);
    setExpression(eval(expression).toString())
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, are you getting any error,s or state not updating?

Comment: actually i am making a calculator and i get error when it calculate two numbers starting from zero like "02+3" it gives error "Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode". so when it starts calculating i want it to remove unneccessary zero but before i remove zero it calculates equation and gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting an updated state from the Logic function, You can use it like this.

```
const Calculate = () => {
  Logic();
  setExpression((exp) => {
    setResult(exp);
    return eval(exp).toString();
  });
};
```